# Screenshot error: XDefaultRootWindow() failed after closing a Tkinter Toplevel --> Python MSS Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter, python-mss

- Ubuntu v22.04
- MSS v7.0.1
- Python 3.10

This issue is practically identical to: [Python: Tkinter + MSS = mss.exception.ScreenShotError: XDefaultRootWindow() failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420723/python-tkinter-mss-mss-exception-screenshoterror-xdefaultrootwindow-fail) - however, their question is unsolved. For a minimum reproducible example, see there.

---

### How my project functions

I have a project that involves controlling video game automation scripts/macros via a Python GUI. Using the tool goes something like this:

1. Run the program, which opens a navigable single-page GUI.
2. Select the game you'd like to automate.
3. Select the script you'd like to run.
4. Configure the options for the script (this involves opening a new Toplevel window in Tkinter).
5. Press `Play` to run the script.
6. System: When the `Play` button is pressed, my program *screenshots* the video game client to locate its window position as well as various UI element positions. This occurs in a function called `win.initialize()`.
7. Optional: The user may pause, resume, or stop the script, or switch to a different script on the fly.

### The problem

#### [Please see this video for a demonstration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1otNI_bgeE1c1JZO1mMprNs5L0bvpYvIg/view?usp=sharing):

The issue I'm experiencing happens between step 4 and 6. Strangely, the *first* time I open the options menu, select/save my options, and close that little pop-up window, the script *will run successfully* - i.e., MSS will not encounter an error when screenshotting the game client. If I stop/restart the script (which *does not require me to re-select options*), it will still work properly. **However, if I change the options by opening the pop-up window again, MSS will throw this error when it attempts to screenshot:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/my_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/customtkinter/widgets/ctk_button.py", line 372, in clicked
    self.command()
  File "/home/my_project/src/view/info_frame.py", line 139, in play_btn_clicked
    self.controller.play_pause()
  File "/home/my_project/src/controller/bot_controller.py", line 21, in play_pause
    self.model.play_pause()
  File "/home/my_project/src/model/bot.py", line 103, in play_pause
    if not self.__initialize_window():
  File "/home/my_project/src/model/bot.py", line 132, in __initialize_window
    self.win.initialize()
  File "/home/my_project/src/model/runelite_bot.py", line 47, in initialize
    if not super().initialize():
  File "/home/my_project/src/utilities/window.py", line 128, in initialize
    a = self.__locate_minimap(client_rect)
  File "/home/my_project/src/utilities/window.py", line 257, in __locate_minimap
    if m := imsearch.search_img_in_rect(imsearch.BOT_IMAGES.joinpath("minimap.png"), client_rect):
  File "/home/my_project/src/utilities/imagesearch.py", line 52, in search_img_in_rect
    im = rect.screenshot()
  File "/home/my_project/src/utilities/geometry.py", line 64, in screenshot
    with mss.mss() as sct:
  File "/home/my_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mss/factory.py", line 34, in mss
    return linux.MSS(**kwargs)
  File "/home/my_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mss/linux.py", line 297, in __init__
    self.root = self.xlib.XDefaultRootWindow(self._get_display(display))
  File "/home/my_project/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mss/linux.py", line 184, in validate
    raise ScreenShotError(f"{func.__name__}() failed", details=details)
mss.exception.ScreenShotError: XDefaultRootWindow() failed

Screenshot error: XDefaultRootWindow() failed, {'retval': <mss.linux.LP_XWindowAttributes object at 0x7f31d8d38ac0>, 
    'args': (<mss.linux.LP_Display object at 0x7f31d8d38740>,)}
```

**This indicates that the issue has something to do with opening and closing the TkToplevel (pop-up) widget.** I cannot explain why this works the first time I select options. From what I can see, the Toplevel widget is being destroyed properly whenever the user closes it or presses the `save` button.

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including debugging details. Did the code on that previous question reproduce your problem? If it was, post the stack trace of that code instead of your code. And what is your platform and software version? I have run that code in my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with the mss 6.1.0 and it works fine.

Comment: I reproduced the problem by closing an opened window and reopening the second window. I'll answer the question.

Comment: @relent95 Edited post with my versions/platform.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in the current MSS. Please report it on [this](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues).

The current implementation changes the current X11 error handler and leaves it afterwards, and it causes a conflict with Tcl/Tk(the backend of Python `tkinter`).(See [this](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/blob/v7.0.1/mss/linux.py#L288) for detail.)

To avoid this, you can initialize an MSS instance before calling any `tkinter` API and reuse it, so not disturbing the `tkinter` module, like the following example.

```
import tkinter as tk
import mss

mss_obj = mss.mss()

root = tk.Tk()
...
try:
    root.mainloop()
finally:
    mss_obj.close()
```

Comment: So to clarify, the workaround is to just have a single MSS instance for the entire program?

Comment: A Issue on GitHub has been made here: https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/220

Comment: The point of the workaround is not to disturb ```tkinter```, by initializing an MSS instance before calling any ```tkinter``` API.